# Intel Pentium D at bus 200?

Tags: cpu, intel-pentium

So I bought a Pentium D 945 from eBay and used it on my motherboard (quite a long time from now). I didn't use the computer that often but lately I decided to use Hardware Monitor on it. I found out that the Bus Speed was 200MHz. Googling the CPU I found out that the CPU should have a Bus of 800MHz?? I ran games and everything heavy usage but the max was still only 200MHz?

The motherbord RC410-M fully supports this CPU and Bus Speed so I don't understand what could be going wrong? Anyone know what could possibly be happening and ways I could possibly fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [frontside bus of the Intel Pentium D 945](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus#Intel_processors) runs at 200MHz, but is "[Quad-pumped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_data_rate)" to give an effective transfer rate of [800MT/s (Mega-transfers per second)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_D#Presler).

The MT/s to MHz transcription is a marketing-ism and is a common misrepresentation when talking about memory transfers.

For example [DDR2-666](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Specification_standards) implies that the data clock is 666MHz, when in fact the memory clock is 166.67MHz, the data I/O bus clock is 333.33MHz, and the data is double-pumped giving an equivalent "666 MHz" (or more correctly 600MT/s) data transfer rate.

Your CPU is fine and operating as intended.